# Bloch state and mirror symmetry

Tags: quantum-mechanics, solid-state-physics

Consider a periodic potential in one dimension, which also has mirror symmetry:
$U(x+a)=U(x)$ and
$U(-x)=U(x)$.
According to Wigner theorem, the corresponding wave function in an energy eigenstate is either symmetric or antisymmetric:
$\Phi(x)=\Phi(-x)$ or $\Phi(x)=-\Phi(-x)$.
However, this is not true for the Bloch function $\Phi(x)=\exp (ikx) u_k(x)$, where $u_k(x)$ is periodic with respect to $a$. How do you explain the contradiction?

Answer (score 2):

What the mirror symmetry implies is that for each Bloch eigenstate $\Psi(x)=e^{ikx}u_k(x)$, its mirror image $\Psi(-x)=e^{-ikx}u_k(-x)$ is another eigenstate with the same energy. Then one can form symmetric/anti-symmetric eigenstates just by linear superposition: $\Psi_\pm(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}[\Psi(x)\pm \Psi(-x)]$.